# R looping with bp function

Tags: r

I have one dataset containing 3 columns: country, year and tdvalue.
I would like to make a loop by country to create a dummy variable (`sd`) having 1 or 0 if the year is a breakpoint by using R `breakpoint` function.
But when I make my code work my `sd` variable always equal 0, while I know that it is the case for some years?

Thanks a lot for your help!

```
library(zoo)
library(sandwich)
library(strucchange)
library(segmented)
library(tree)

tabo<-read.table("boucle.txt", header=T, sep="\t")

Fonction.bp<-function(b)
  bp.inf <- breakpoints(tabo$year ~ tabo$tradevaluein1000usd , tabo = tabo[b,], h = 8)
  t<-breakdates(confint(bp.inf))
  for (i in 1:nrow(t)) {
    res <- ifelse(tabo$year[b] == t[i,1] , 1, 0)
    return(res)
  }
}

numero<-1:nrow(tabo)
tabo$sd<-lapply(tabo$code_o,Fonction.bp)
```

data sample:

```
code_o -origin  -year   -tradevaluein1000usd

ABW Aruba   1988    375.059
ABW Aruba   1989    3458.656
ABW Aruba   1990    2924.484
ABW Aruba   1991    140509.4
```

etc for several countries

> dput(tabo):

```
structure(list(code_o = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("ABW", "AFG", "AGO"), class = "factor"), 
    origin = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Afghanistan", "Angola", 
    "Aruba"), class = "factor"), year = c(1988L, 1989L, 1990L, 
    1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 1999L, 
    2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 
    2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L, 1988L, 1989L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 
    1993L, 1994L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 
    2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 
    2011L, 2012L, 1988L, 1989L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 
    1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 
    2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2012L
    ), tradevaluein1000usd = c(375.059, 3458.656, 2924.484, 140509.4, 
    326377, 548739.3, 570287.9, 673563.2, 809647.7, 1021996, 
    680243.7, 944974.8, 1950097, 1416807, 1055372, 1276015, 2503752, 
    3908081, 4294362, 4654180, 5523432, 2203173, 272596.5, 4450387, 
    127760.6, 121861.2, 125059.8, 134163.4, 115283.5, 82499.51, 
    68673.89, 97143.18, 104883.2, 124654.5, 155892.9, 167802.9, 
    137721, 153405.3, 99146.39, 103894.9, 190640.9, 209073.9, 
    264083.6, 254765.3, 408123.6, 507407, 1283451, 609946.1, 
    486418.4, 67638.02, 1112926, 3120863, 4082248, 3290223, 3796494, 
    3283747, 3175830, 3614761, 4669298, 4618304, 3501481, 4478671, 
    7878114, 6290144, 7344164, 8563406, 11900000, 20700000, 30200000, 
    39500000, 65700000, 38900000, 50600000, 59400000, 8839811
    ), sd = list(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("code_o", "origin", "year", 
"tradevaluein1000usd", "sd"), row.names = c(NA, -75L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: please `dput` your data, or point us to the source, so that your problem is easily reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

You've got **bad** code.

If you expect people's time, you *must* put more effort in.

Your function doesn't work: `tabo['AGO',]`, `tabo['AFG',]`, and `tabo['ABW',]` all are empty, as there are no rows with these names. I think you probably want to subset the data, using something like:

```
tabo[tabo$code_o == 'AGO',]
tabo[tabo$code_o == 'AFG',]
tabo[tabo$code_o == 'ABW',]
```

`bp.inf` is the same regardless of if we include the code `tabo = tabo[b,]` -- as you're calling the items the the regression from the global environment, and not passing in a data-frame (as you're giving `tabo` rather than `data`).  If this is confusing forget about it ...

The bottom line is that there are a few erros in the line that finds breakpoints. You need to change to something like `bp.inf <- breakpoints(year ~ tradevaluein1000usd, data = tabo[tabo$code_o == 'AGO',], h = 8)`.

Note also, your function doesn't open with a `{` so it doesn't work at all.